# What is this file: /usr/bin/[?

Tags: 11.04, bash, files

The name of the file is '[' . When I open it up in vi it looks like it's a copy of 'test'. It's owned by root.

Comment: What's the output of `stat /bin/[`?

Comment: @SirCharlo  File: `/usr/bin/['  
  Size: 30244      Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file  
Device: 805h/2053d Inode: 2499684     Links: 1  
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)  
Access: 2012-08-23 14:50:24.545242581 -0400  
Modify: 2011-02-23 08:22:21.000000000 -0500  
Change: 2012-07-09 22:31:52.133720601 -0400

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That file is supposed to be there (or under `/usr/bin/[`). It allows you to type, for instance, `[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && echo ".bashrc exists"`, which is equivalent to `test -f $HOME/.bashrc && echo ".bashrc exists"`.

Reality is a bit more complicated, since bash overrides `/usr/bin/[` with its own `[`, so you can use the `[` executable by providing a full path, `/usr/bin/[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && echo ".bashrc exists"`.

Comment: I'm curious now. I don't have that file..

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/[`.

Comment: @pablomme You're the **man**!

Answer (score 5):

It is a version of `test` that requires a `]` as last argument. It's often used in shell scripts, like in

```
if [ -e some_file ]; then ...
```

(but in most modern shell, like Bash, it's a builtin command).

It's required by POSIX